# Mathematically inclined books on Signal Processing Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

First off, i know this may seem off topic but i could not find help in signal processing communities so i was hoping there would be people here who both love mathematics and have interest in signal processing.

I'm an electronics engineering student with high inclination to analysis and pure mathematics ( abstract algebra/linear algebra ... ).

I was just wondering if there was any book ( or any resource ) that treats signal and systems and signal processing with a lot of mathematics rigour ( actually doing proper complex analysis, using functional analysis and linear algebra rigorously to explain convolution, fourier, laplace,haar, hilbert, z transforms for example ).

I'm very disapointed with the books i've read ( Oppenhein, Lathi and related ) on Signal Processing Theory because they actually throw most of the beauty of analysis and algebra away, focusing on the computational side, treating ( undeservedly ) mathematics as a mere tool.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are some examples of things missing in, say, Oppenheim that you'd like to see? Are the proofs incomplete?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/427/21075)

Answer (score 5):

My favorite is [Foundations of Signal Processing](http://foundationsofsignalprocessing.org) by Martin Vetterli, Jelena Kovačević and Vivek Goyal. If you like linear algebra, then this is it.

I was a student at EPFL, in the early days when Martin Vetterli was still teaching a course on advanced signal processing, the material of which eventually formed into this great book; true to the word in the title 'foundations'.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 3):

[The Mathematics of Signal Processing](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/numerical-analysis/mathematics-signal-processing) by Damelin and Miller that came out recently covers some of the topics you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my book, "Intuitive Guide to Fourier Analysis and Spectral Estimation." I explain the quandary of time and frequency domain, negative frequency  and all the other weighty matters related to signal processing and DSP.

Charan Langton

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've seen is Stephane Mallat's *A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing*.